# Boots into blinking cursor and black screen after 'mount -o remount,rw /'

Tags: boot, disk-usage

I have used the command
`mount -o remount,rw/`, now I am unable to boot normally. Using the recovery menu, it seems there is no space left on my device. Unfortunately, when I try to remove files from the disk, the total disk size seems to shrink and the available space stays at zero.
Any idea what may be going on and how to correct it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the missing space and not to the command `mount`, I used

`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda8` to do some cleaning and I was able to boot normally.